# What conditions a density function undefined on finite set, must obey to produce a distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability

Let's suppose we have $I_i=]a_{i-1},a_i[, i\in \{1,...,n\}$, with $a_0=-\infty$ and $a_n=+\infty$.

Let $f$ be continuous on its domain which is $\bigcup_{i \in \{1,...,n\}}I_i$. With $F(x)=\int^x_{a_0}f(u) du$.

If I want to be sure that $F$ is distribution function, what conditions on $f$ would I need to satisfy? Let's assume I'm using Riemann integrals, and the density is associated to a continuous r.v. .

For $F(a_{i}^+)=F(a_i)$ (right-continuity), $\lim_{x->a_i^+}\int^x_{a_0}f(x)dx=\int^{a_i}_{a_0}f(x)dx$. But in this case, for $\int^{a_i}_{a_0}f(x)dx$ to exist, $\lim_{x->a_i^-}\int^x_{a_0}f(x)dx$ must exist and be finite, right? So, I must have $F(a_{i}^+)=F(a_i^-)$. Will this imply that $f(a_i^+)=f(a_i^-)$?

For $F$ to be non-decreasing, $f$ for $x \in I_i$ must be non-negative, and this seems to be enough given the above comment.

For $F(-\infty)=0$ and $F(+\infty)=1$, I don't see what type of special behaviour $f$ would necessarily need to have.

Am I right?

I am looking for an answer using knowledge only from calculus and a 1st course in probability.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If $f$ is continuous (as you mention) then it is necessary and enough if $f$ is measurable, does not take negative values and satisfies $\int f(x)dx=1$. Then automatically the induced $F(x)$ is a CDF.

Comment: @drhab, I was looking for an answer without using measure theory, only calculus and a first course in probability. I've edited the question. Thanks for the comment

Comment: You can leave out the term measurable in my former comment if $f$ is already continuous. Then what remains does not appeal on measure theory.

Comment: @drhab How would it change, if $F_X=\lambda F_{X_{d}}+(1-\lambda)F_{X_{c}}$, where $X_{d}$ is a discrete r.v. and $X_{c}$ is a continuous r.v.? In this case, assume we still have $f$ continuous in its domain.

Comment: Then a probability density for $X_c$ might exists (not always, there are continuous rv's that have no density) but (if $0<\lambda<1$) not one for $X$. Secondly a probability mass function for $X_d$ exists but not one for $X$.